# Text highlighting?

Tags: react-konva, konva, konvajs-reactjs

I'm trying to use the output of AWS Textract (OCR) to rebuild a text document from the scan of a (non-text) PDF. I have an array of lines of text on the page with offset positions, so I think it would be possible to simply position these as several (many) `TextPath`s.

I then want to allow a user to select portions of one or more `TextPaths` to "highlight." For highlighting, it could be simply a `Rect` overlaid on text with an opacity to appear as a highlighted box. Imagine Google Docs or Word, but for highlighted text.

Any ideas on how I can achieve or approach drawing multiple `Rects` over the `TextPath` objects to appear as highlighting? Any demos of text highlighting or the like?